# CSS :after pseudo-class and content: declaration

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I'm trying to add pipes between a set of links using css `:after` to add content

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbPFR/1/

For some reason, it's adding the pipes inside the `<a>` tags instead of after them.

Basically all i'm looking for is to get a list like this:

Link1 | Link 2 | Link 3

Any suggestions about what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :after pseudo-element actually works this way. The naming is a bit confusing, as the pseudo-element is not inserted as the following sibling but as the last child element.

You could try to use list-style-item, but I guess that is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Aron - I couldn't find where this is described as expected outcome in the docs - you wouldn't happen to have any links to share describing this in more detail would you?

Comment: Well, I have to agree the specs are a bit vague here. The only thing they say are (in http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after) "The ':before' and ':after' pseudo-elements can be used to insert generated content before or after an element's content". The keyword here is "content". I.e. not the tag itself, but the contents of the tag (its child nodes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the anchors, as the :after is adding them after. You can use a list to create a child container:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
</ul>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/atqNy/1/